# Custom styled radio buttons using ASP.NET MVC Helpers

Tags: html, css, razor, html-helper

I am struggling to style `Html.RadioButtonFor()` form elements in my ASP.NET MVC project. I'm trying to replicate something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/2374/

But with my HTML form section that looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Presave.IsTrack, true) Track</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Presave.IsTrack, false) Album</label>
</div>
```

None of my styles are picked up when I do stuff like:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:yellow;
}
```

The css for the label outline (taken from the fiddle) in my project works fine though

```
label {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 90;
}
```

but that's about it, I cannot get the background color style for the selected element. What additional syntax do I have to add for this to be picked up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` selector is looking for the label right after a `checked` radio and the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Presave.IsTrack, true) Track</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Presave.IsTrack, false) Album</label>
</div>
```

will generate radio buttons that are inside labels e.g.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label><input type="radio" />...</label>
    <label><input type="radio" />...</label>
</div>
```

Putting the labels right after the `@RadioButtonFor` should do the trick:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Presave.IsTrack, true, new { id = "track" })
    <label for="track">Track</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Presave.IsTrack, false, new { id = "album" }) 
    <label for="album">Album</label>
</div>
```

Comment: oof so close! So now the stylings work, but since the label is now detached from the RadioButton, if you click on the label text, it doesn't select the radio button :(

Comment: okay so I fixed this by adding an id to the RadioButtonFor and then using that same id as the `for` tag on the label. Now it works as expected, if you add that to your answer, i will mark as correct! @StaticBeagle

Comment: @JordanLewallen good catch! I've added the id's to the `RadioButtonFor's`.

Comment: @JordanLewallen you bet. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Presave.IsTrack, true,new { @class = "hello" }) Track</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Presave.IsTrack, false, new { @class = "hello" }) Album</label>
</div>
```

Comment: adding a class does not help the :checked attribute for a radio button input though ???